# Angular JS route parameters with limited options

Tags: angularjs, url, url-parameters, ngroute

I just started using Angular and currently using 1.4.2. 
I would like to know how to have only three options for the URL, `/:type` - create, update, and view.

They all use the same controller, so I don't want to have separate whens such as

```
.when('/create ... , .when('/update ... , .when('/view ... .
```

I don't want any other options to be passed beside these.
It would be great if I could get some help! 
Thanks :)

Comment: Create 3 separate rules.

Comment: You mean three `.when` cases? but that's what I wanted to avoid cause they will all be using the same controller. Within that controller, the flags will be set accordingly.

Comment: You can use the same controller, or different controllers. Not sure I understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just get the parameter from $routeParams service on your controller and do whatever logic you want to do with it. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

**route config**

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/yourroute/:type", {
        template: "default"
        templateUrl: "template.html",
        controller: "Controller"
    });
```

**controller function**

```
function Controller($routeParams) {
    switch($routeParams.type) {
        case "create":
            ...
        case "update":
            ...
        case "view":
            ...
        default:
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I think this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

but you want 3 différents url ? You should use ui-router and stateHelperProvider to use child statement il you don't want to declare multiple when. You should be able to do something like

```
stateHelperProvider.state({
            name: 'root',
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            abstract: true,
            children: [
                    {
                        name: 'create',
                        url: '/create',
                        templateUrl: 'mypath.html',
                        controller: 'myCtrl',
                        data: {
                            type: 'create'
                        }
                    },
                {
                    name: 'view',
                    url: '/view',
                    templateUrl: 'mypath.html',
                    controller: 'myCtrl',
                    data: {
                        type: 'view'
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'update',
                    url: '/update',
                    templateUrl: 'mypath.html',
                    controller: 'myCtrl',
                    data: {
                        type: 'update'
                }
                },
            ]
            });
```

whit each time a data with your datas. 
But i don't understand whu you not declare 3 "when"

Comment: yes, depending on the type I pass in, the flags will be assigned. So for example, if the type is view, then I'll disable the fields.

Comment: Thanks! :) But this seems like it's useful when you have different html file and controllers for each child.